# How to display event dates with optional times in WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, display-template, client-side-rendering

In our Events web part we want to display Start & End dates for Calendar events.
Some of our events are multi-day and probably have a midnight time, and these we want to display like so:

e.g.
**29 September 2017 - 31 September 2017**

However other events are single day and may span a few hours. In this case it should be displayed like so:

e.g.
**29 September 2017 13:00 - 14:00**

What is the best way of achieving this? Can it be done with mapped properties only or will I have to use a mix of some JavaScript date parsing and CSR template script?